# Folder permission Zend Framework project

Tags: git, zend-framework, zend-framework2, file-permissions

What folder permissions and owners do you set on a ZF2 project?
And what about the .git folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same structure than the ZendSkeleton application, you only need write permissions on the `data` folder.

Personnaly, I prefer to add a `runtime` folder for all volatile data like cache.

You will possibly need write permisions on subfolders located in `public` if you have upload features in your application, like a `public/uploads` folder. You may also have a folder for `assets` that will need write permission.

Concerning the `.git` folder, it will not be deployed on your production server so you only need to setup permissions in development environment.

For all the others, a 0755 mode is sufficient.

Comment: Is it better to assign 777 permissions or chown www-data:www-data to the data folder?

Comment: 777 is overkill 0755 is sufficient, unless you have a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Folder / File Permissions are all based on your personal setup and every answer you receive here will be completely different as it will also be based on their setup.

The default answer would be to have your Folders / Files owned by the User/Group you are uploading to.

Pending which web-server you are running, this could also be perhaps apache:apache or http:http or nginx:nginx. This seriously is all based on your current setup.